# Is there a way to step in to CasperJS code and Debug step by step

Tags: debugging, remote-debugging, casperjs

Though I have been using CasperJS for some time, and rely on console logging for debugging. I was wondering if there is any IDE which support CasperJS step by step debugging or there is other way(remote debugging) to step in to CasperJS code? Has anybody successfully done it? Any information will be helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 24):

When I want to debug with CasperJS, I do the following : I launch my script with slimerJS (it opens a firefox window so I can easilly see click problem, problems of form filling-ajax return error, media uploading...-, and in which step the code blocks).

With that I don't often need to look at the console and I don't call this.capture('img.jpg') several times to debug (for now i don't test responsive design so i don't need to use capture, take a look at PhantomCSS if you test it).

I use slimerJS to debug (always with casper), but phantomJS in continuous Integration-jenkins- (headless), though you can use slimerjs too (being headless) with xvfb on linux or Mac.

But sometimes i have to look at the console for more details, so I use these options (you can call them in command line too) :

```
casper.options.verbose = true;
casper.options.logLevel ="debug";
```

Name your closures will be useful with these options, because the name will be displayed.

I don't think there is an IDE : if a step fail, the stack with all the following steps stops anyway (well it's still possible to do a 'sort of hack' using multiple wait -and encapsulate them- to perform differents closures and have the result of all of them, even if one of them fail; but in this case we are not stacking synchronous steps, but executing asynchronous instructions : take care about timeout and logical flow if you try it). Care : i said 'if a step fail', if it's just an instruction in a closure which fails, of course the following steps will be execute.

So a closure which fails -> following steps are executed.
A step which fails (ex : thenOpen(fssfsf) with fssfsf not defined), the stack will stop. 
Multiple wait() can be done asynchronously.

So if you have a lot of bugs and execute your tests sequentially (stacking steps), you can only debug them one by one, or by closure for independant step functions-I think an IDE could work in this case- (->for one file. The stacks are of course independent if you launch a folder). And usually at the beginning you launch your file each time you finish a step. And when you're used to the tool, you write the whole script at once.

In most cases, bug are due to asynchrone, scope, context problems (actually js problems, though casper simplifies asynchronous problems : "The callback/listener stuff is an implementation of the Promise pattern.")  :

- If you want to loop a suit of instructions, don't forget the IIFE or use the casper each function, and encompass all with a then() statement (or directly eachThen). I can show some exemples if needed. Otherwise it will loop the last index 'i.length' times, there isn't loop scope in js, by default i has the same reference.
- When you click on a link at the end of a step, use a wait()-step function too- statement after; instead of a then(). If i've well understood the then() statement, it's launched when the previous step is completed. So it's launched just after the click(). If this click launches an ajax return, and your following step scrape or test the result of this ajax return, it will randomly fail, because you haven't explicitly ask to wait for the resource. I saw some issues like that in my first tests.
- Don't mixt the two context : casper environment and page DOM environment. Use the evaluate function() for passing from one to the other. In the evaluate function, you can pass an argument from the casper context to the page DOM...

...Like that :

```js
var casperContext = "phantom";

casper.evaluate(function(pageDomContext) {
    console.log("will echo ->phantom<- in the page DOM environment : " + pageDomContext + ", use casper.on('remote.message') to see it in the console");
}, casperContext);
```

Or you can see it directly in the browser with slimerJS using alert() instead of console.log().

- Use setFiltrer to handle prompt and confirm box.
- If your website exists in mobile version too, you can manipulate the userAgent for your mobile tests.
- You can call node modules in a casperJS file, in files using the tester module too. Well it's not entirely true, see [use node module from casper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387854/use-a-node-module-from-casperjs). Some core node features are implemented in phantom (and slimer too), like fs, child process, but they are not always well documented. I prefer to execute my tests with node so. Node is useful to launch your tests in parallel (child process). I suggest you to execute as many processes as you have core. Well, it depends of your type of script, with just normal scenario (open a page and check some elements) I can execute 10 child process in parallel whithout random failure (local computer), but with some elements which are slow to load (as multi svg, sometimes xml...), use <kbd>require('os').cpus().length</kbd> or a script like that : [Repeat a step X times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23891143/casperjs-how-to-repeat-a-step-x-times-onwaittimeout). Otherwise you will have random failure, even if you increase the timeout. When it crashes, you can't do anything other that `reload()` the page.

You can then integrate your tests in jenkins using the xunit command. Just specify differents index for each log.xml files, jenkins (XUnit -> JUnit) will manage them : pattern *.xml.

I know i didn't really answer your question, but i think to debug, list the main specific problems remains the best way.

There are still useful functions to debug :

```js
var fs = require('fs');
fs.write("results.html", this.getPageContent(), 'w');
```

I prefer this way rather than this.debugHTML(). I can check in my results.html file if there are missing tags (relative to the browser using firebug or another tool). Or sometimes if i need to check just one tag, output the result in the console isn't a problem, so : this.getHTML("my selector"); and you can still pipe the log result : `casperjs test test.js > test.html`

- Another trick : if you execute your tests in local, sometimes the default timeout isn't sufficient (network freeze) (5sec).

So -> 10sec :

```
casper.options.waitTimeout = 10000;
```

Some differences between Phantom and Slimer :

- With slimer, if you set casper.options.pageSettings.loadImages = false; and in your file you try to scrape or test the weight/height.... of an element, it will work with slimer but not with phantom. So set it to true in the specific file to keep the compatibility.
- Need to specify an absolute path with slimer (with include, import->input media, ...).

Example :

```js
this.page.uploadFile('input[name="media"]', fs.absolute(require('system').args[4]).split(fs.separator).slice(0, -1).join(fs.separator) + '/../../../../avatar.jpg');
```

To include a file from the root folder (work in every subdir/OS, better than previous inclusion) -you could also do it nodeLike using require()-:

```js
phantom.injectJs(fs.workingDirectory + '/../../../../global.js');
```