# can I view the tests scripts running in casperjs in browser for easy tracking

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Hi I'm using jquery & Ajax as a front end in my web application , so I'm working on Automating the test environment using casperjs. because of using jquery - ajax, I'm unable to track the application whether the page is loaded or not and many other events. so In development time I'm thinking to view the actions in browser rather in text mode.

is there any possibility to view the test scripts running through browser actions?

Comment: What am I missing here? You ask for run CasperJS in browser and get a SlimerJS and it's done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use the slimerJS (gecko -> firefox) engine in casper : 
http://slimerjs.org/
It opens firefox and you will see your automatic tests in the browser.

This answer could interest you : [Is there a way to step in to CasperJS code and Debug step by step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820228/is-there-a-way-to-step-in-to-casperjs-code-and-debug-step-by-step)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, since SlimerJS 0.8, and with CasperJS 1.1beta1 or higher. Just launch CasperJS as usual by adding --engine=slimerjs on the command line.

Comment: Yes, and if you want to launch a folder : casperjs ./folder/ --engine=slimerjs works but not casperjs folder/ --engine=slimerjs (both work with phantom)