# Error: Cannot find module 'libxmljs'

Tags: phantomjs, libxml-js

I am trying to parse xml using phantomjs for the following file, `documentpreviewer1.js`

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

var url = "http://xxx/sitemap.xml";

page.open(url, function(status){
    if(status != 'success'){
                console.log('Unable to access cfc');
    }
    else
    {
                var xml = page.content;
                var libxmljs = require("libxmljs");
                var xmlDoc = libxmljs.parseXml(xml);

                var url1 = xmlDoc.get('//urlset/url[0]/loc');
                console.log(url1);
    }
});
```

when I  run the above code, I get the following error

cmd `sudo phantomjs documentpreivewer1.js`

```
Error: Cannot find module 'libxmljs'

  phantomjs://bootstrap.js:289
  phantomjs://bootstrap.js:254 in require
  documentpreivewer1.js:13
  :/modules/webpage.js:281
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libxmljs is a node.js module. Although phantomjs can be installed through npm (doesn't need to be) it is not a node.js module. It doesn't share any built-in module with node.js ([`fs`](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/) seems the same, but is not equal to node.js fs).

You can use some node.js modules in phantomjs (See [Use a node module from casperjs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24387854/1816580) for a related question), but it doesn't seem like you could use libxmljs in phantomjs, because it depends on node-bindings which uses `fs` and `path` modules. You will have to change the implementation so that all dependencies can be expressed with phantomjs capabilities.

An alternative might be to use [phantom-node](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) or [spookyjs](https://github.com/WaterfallEngineering/SpookyJS) for a casperjs node.js module.