# is it possible to send email with casperjs?

Tags: node.js, casperjs, mailgun

I am having a hard time finding examples of how to send an email with casperjs. This is my attempt so far... 
- I successfully got an API key from Mailgun.
- I found 2 npm modules such as 'mailgun', and 'mailgun-js'
- I loaded them and verified mailgun is loaded globablly and locally.. 
When I run my casper file.
$ casperjs casper-test.js 
I get the following error:
'undefined' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new mailgun')

```
var Mailgun = require('mailgun').Mailgun;
var mg = new Mailgun('key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa078a515af');

sendText('no-reply@at.com',
     ['myemail@gmail.com'],
     'Testing, casper-test',
     {'X-Campaign-Id': 'something'},
     function(err) { err && console.log(err) });
```

My questions are... 
Am I even going in the right direction? is casperjs capable of firing off one of these modules?
If so please let me know how I can fix

Comment: CasperJS/PhantomJS is not node.js. If you need node.js, then run it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24389819/4179009   This answer explains the confusion between CasperJS and node.js NPM modules.  They are not the same.  That mailgun module is to be used with node.js, not CasperJS

Comment: so than does anyone know how to send an email from within casperjs?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
You can do it with http api:

```
casper.setHttpAuth('api', 'YOUR-SECRET-API-KEY');
casper.thenOpen('https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR-MG-DOMAIN/messages', {
    method: 'post',
    data:   {
        'from': 'mailgun@YOUR-MG-DOMAIN',
        'to': 'target',
        'subject':  'Hello.',
        'text':  'message'
    }
});
```