# PhatomJS: How can I use(require) an npm module in phatom js?

Tags: node.js, module, npm, phantomjs, runtime-error

i'm trying to require() and use this [logging module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/noogger) (it has some dependencies also) in phatomJS but it fails and prints this error:

```
C:\node\scrap>phantomjs app.js
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: process

  phantomjs://platform/index.js:3
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: process

  phantomjs://platform/index.js:9
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'chalk.bold.red')

  phantomjs://platform/index.js:29
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'log.info('All settings loaded, start with exe
cution')')

  phantomjs://code/app.js:16 in global code
```

I don't know why or what's wrong ? what am I missing ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a node module from casperjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387854/use-a-node-module-from-casperjs)

Comment: There is no `process` module in PhantomJS,

Comment: Keep in mind, PhantomJS is a headless browser — which makes it great for testing things that are reliant on a browser, such as accessing document and window objects.

If you want to use modules within Phantom JS, I would imagine that you would need to jump through many of the same hoops one would need to jump through to get the same code to run in non-headless browsers.

Comment: Hum, so basically it's not possible, is there any workaround solution for this ?

Comment: I ran in to this as well. A couple of things to try - this issue is with the module you require. Look at the modules it depends on - those are causing you a problem.